# bootstrap change color of navbar-nav hover

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find what i should modify in bootstrap to change the mouse-over background color of elements in a navbar. This is the element i want to change:

```
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>

                @Html.ActionLink("Distribusjonsenhetsadministrasjon", "Dea", "Home")

            </li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

I managed to change the normal background color and text color without any problem. But not the mouse-over background color, i tried to change every possible hover connected to a nav class i could find in the css.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 .navbar-nav>li:hover{
    color: #333;
    background-color:red;
    }
```

Comment: Additionally, learn to use browser's built in developer tools. This would make your task as simple as right clicking on the navbar item and selecting 'Inspect element', and looking at its css properties.